# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '12,652'

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping

I am trying to get no of reviews count of a particular product

The code is:

```
total_reviews = soup.find("div", {"class": "feature"}).findNext(
    "span", {"id": "acrCustomerReviewText"}).string
x = ''
for number in total_reviews:
    if number == ' ':
        break
    else:
        x = x + number

num_reviews =int(x)
```

Comment: an `int` with a comma in it? Really? C'mon! and Good luck ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the comma with an empty string using `str.replace()`:

```
num_reviews = int(x.replace(",", ""))
```